# Searching for just ? and spaces in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar` column that had some `nvarchar` data inserted, so I now have records that contain data such as '? ???'

```
select * from table where EnglishName LIKE '%[? ]%'
```

Returns everything, and other variations of `LIKE '[? ]'` don't return the data I'm after.

How can I select records that ONLY contain Question marks, and Optionally contain a Space?

```
'??' - return
'? ?' - return
' ?' - return
'? chen' - don't return
' ' - don't return
'  chen' - don't return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an additional predicate to filter out non `?` or space characters:

```
WHERE (col LIKE '%[? ]%') AND (col NOT LIKE '%[^? ]%')
```

The above will *also* select records containing *just* spaces. If you want to filter these records out as well, then simply use:

```
WHERE (col LIKE '%[?]%') AND (col NOT LIKE '%[^? ]%')
```

Comment: This will also return records with just spaces, and I need to exclude them (another team will handle that data cleanup)

Comment: @StormRider01 Have you checked the edit I made? It addresses exactly this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, n VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '??'),
(2, '? ?'),
(3, ' ?'),
(4, ' ? '),
(5, '? '),
(6, ' ? ? '),
(7, '? chen??'),
(8, ' chen '),
(9, 'chen  ?? ??'),
(10, ' chen ?')


SELECT * FROM @t 
WHERE n LIKE '%[?]%' AND n NOT LIKE '%[^? ]%[?]%' AND n NOT LIKE '%[?]%[^? ]%'
```

Output:

```
id  n
1   ??
2   ? ?
3    ?
4    ? 
5   ? 
6    ? ?
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're only doing this as part of a manual maintenance operation. If that's the case, this could be good enough:

```
where len(replace([EnglishName], '?', '')) = 0
```

This will replace all the `?` with an empty string and take the length excluding any trailing spaces - so if the string is *only* `?` and spaces, its length is going to be zero.

If my assumption is wrong and you're using this as part of your application proper, I'd avoid hacks like this. There probably *is* a more reasonable way of accomplishing this.

**EDIT:** To handle the additional constraint of "do not select names that are only spaces", you can just add `and len([EnglishName]) > 0`.

Comment: `where len(trim(replace([EnglishName], '?', ''))) = 0` ?

Comment: if there can be spaces `where len(replace(replace([EnglishName], '?', ''), ' ', '?')) = 0`

Comment: @HingeSight You don't need to `trim`, `len` automatically excludes trailing whitespace. I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: @Luaan ahh, and in our case - all the white spaces. This is my favorite answer anyway.